# Table with one row ignoring number of columns

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a table where the rows are clickable. When a row is clicked, I want to show input fields.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-mountain-oye5rw?file=/src/App.js

For now just assume the word "test" is the input fields. I want to show/hide depending on row click

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For row click you need to add click event handler for each row like,

```
<tr key={el.id} data-rowid={el.id} onClick={() => { showInputHandler(el.id) }}>
```

Then you need to check the selected id and store it in the state like,

```
  const showInputHandler = (id) => {
    setShowInput((prev) => {
      if (prev === id) {
        return;
      }
      return id;
    });
  };
```

Then add condition to display the input,

```
{showInput === el.id && <div>Some input</div>}
```

**Forked Sandbox:**

[image: Edit exciting-dubinsky-ed9519]